# Hours and Minutes addition in Solaris

Tags: solaris, date

I work in a `solaris` server and the `date -d` option is not there. No `gdate` as well.

Here's what I have which works in Linux:

```
date -d "$hr:$mi $duration minutes" +'%H%M'
```

where `$hr` and `$mi` are hours and mins, `$duration` is in minutes.

When I run like this in Linux, I get this:

```
date -d "23:28 60 minutes" +'%H%M'
0028
```

When I run this in `solaris`, I get:

```
date: illegal option -- d Usage: date [-u] ...
```

Is there an `awk` solution here since my `perl` is ancient?

Requote, I'm having the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208473/calculating-time-adding-minutes-bash), only I don't have the luxury of using `date -d`. I need a one liner `python` or `perl`.

Comment: Do you have `ksh93` shell available to you?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 no, I don't have `ksh93`. Only `ksh` or `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a single little difficulty : splitting arround ":", there is an awk function : `split(what,where,sep)`.

I tried in a solaris (it is a one line command)

```
echo 23:28 60 |
 awk '{split($1,H,":") ; printf "%2d:%02d\n",H[1]+(H[2]+$2)/60, (H[2]+$2)%60 }'
```

where

- split($1,H,":") will put 23 in H[1] and 28 in H[2]

use

```
echo 23:28 60 |
 awk '{split($1,H,":") ; printf "%2d:%02d\n",(H[1]+(H[2]+$2)/60)%24, (H[2]+$2)%60 }'
```

to stay in 0-23 range for hour. change format string in printf to `"%02d:%02d\n"` to have a leading `0`

Comment: Interesting. I'll check this out when I reach home. I've decided to install Solaris on a VM and try anyway as this was nagging me for a long time today. Thanks!

Comment: This gives me `24:28`. I need it to be `00:28`. The `60` in the question is not constant, it varies - sometimes it'd be `120` or even `600`. In that case, I don't want the result to show over 24 hours.

Comment: That just about does it! Thank you! `echo 23:28 60 |
 awk '{split($1,H,":") ; printf "%2d:%02d\n",(H[1]+(H[2]+$2)/60)%24, (H[2]+$2)%60 }'`

Answer (score 0):

With awk, you could do the following:

```
awk -v dayt="2017 11 10 23 28 23" '{tmstmp=mktime(dayt)+60;print strftime("%M:%S",tmstmp)}' <<< ""
```

Pass the FULL date and time to awk with the -v flag and then use the awk mktime to get a number representation of the date/time, adding 60 and then strftime to convert the representation to the required format.

Comment: I'll check this on Monday as I've lost access to my system. Thanks for the answer and have a good weekend!

Comment: I guess I need `%H%M` in the answer, and this works in `Linux`, but not in `Solaris`. I get `syntax error: < unexpected`

Comment: 1) I am not sure solaris's awk will accept `mktime/strftime` function, maybe `gawk` will. 2) you can use a second variable instead fo `60`. 3) you can also use `echo | ...`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a experimental hack but works with modern versions of `bash`.  I tested it on CentOS 7 and Fedora 26

```
#!/bin/bash

hr="23"
mi="28"
duration="60"

printf '%(%H%M)T\n' "$((-(19 * 60 * 60) + (hr * 60 * 60) + (mi * 60) + (duration * 60) ))"
```

Result is `0028`.

Comment: Hmmm. This works on a `Ubuntu` `bash` (I get 1058 instead of 0028 but I guess that's timezone thing?), but not on `Solaris` `bash` :D No idea why, but I'm getting this error - `bash: printf: '(': invalid format character`. I've double checked, did not mess up the braces.

Comment: What version of `bash` on Solaris?   Looks like an old version where %T not supported.  What version of Solaris?

Comment: Version 10 of `Solaris` and version 3.2.51(1) of `bash`